# Writing to the same file from two child processes

Tags: c, linux, file-io

The following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILE "out.txt"

int main() { 
  // Creates an empty file
  close(open(FILE, O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT, 0600));

  fork();

  close(1);
  open(FILE, O_WRONLY);

  execlp("date", "date", NULL);
}
```

Creates a file named out.txt with the following content:

```
Tue  4 Dec 21:21:54 GMT 2018
```

I don't understand why there is only one line with the date and time.

My expectation would be that each of the two child processes should close their respective standard output file descriptors and, now that they are free, reassign them to out.txt. So I would expect to see two lines in the file, one from each child process. Why doesn't that happen?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: They both start writing at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Because you `open()` after the `fork()`?

Comment: Bad idea to `#define FILE` and at the same time `#include <stdio.h>` because it includes a `#define FILE ...` as well

Comment: @EOF You are right that putting the fork after opening the file results in two date lines in the file. But why does it make a difference?

Comment: @Marc Because in Unix, there are both file *descriptors* (the `int` you get from `open()`) and file *descriptions*, which are the corresponding entity in the kernel. The file *description* contains the current offset into the file, and the file *descriptors* in the two `fork()`ed processes refer to the same file *description*, if they started out from the same `open()`.

Comment: @Marc Effectively, it's an early Unix design flaw: if the file *descriptors* kept the offset, a `fork()`ed child process that writes to an output would not advance the file offset in the parent. After the child terminates and the parent (for example, a shell) might want to write to the output (or `fork()` a second child), and then the first child's output would be overwritten.

Comment: @EOF That's a great explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`open(FILE, O_WRONLY);` places the offset at the beginning of the file. Both processes write the current date to the beginning of the file -- one of them will write over the other, but since they're both writing the same string it's impossible to detect.

Setting `O_APPEND` on the second `open()` will get you the results you expect.

(As an aside, don't use the name `FILE` for your preprocessor macro. It's already defined as a type in `<stdio.h>`.)

Comment: If I move the command `fork();` to after `open(FILE, O_WRONLY);` it does write the date twice. Why is that?